# aws postgres rds using ansible

Tags: postgresql, ansible, amazon-rds

I am trying to deploy a postgres db on AWS RDS using ansible. However, I run into problems with the size of the database which I specify as 20 GB (the max for the free tier)

```
"msg": "Failed to create instance: Storage size for Engine Name: postgres and Storage Type: io1 must be between 100 and 6144. Currently specified storage size is 20"
```

Everything works fine if I create the database manually via the dashboard. Any reason why it does not work via the command line tools?

Comment: just curious, does my answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using RDS Provisioned IOPS ? if yes, should be `iops: 100`

> AWS - Provisioned IOPS volumes can range in size from 100 GB to 6 TB for
>   MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL
>
> Ansible - iops - Specifies the number of IOPS for the instance. Used only when
>   command=create or command=modify. Must be an integer greater than
>   1000.